# Render products grouped by dynamic category

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a catalog page with a sidebar which contains a dynamic list:

[image: Sidebar]

This sidebar lists `products.category` and updates whenever there is a new category created/removed.

#### What I want to achieve

Is to be able to show the filtered table based on category that was clicked. **Kind of like using `props`** so I can use `products.category` to automatically fill the filter without hardcoding each category.

*I may be approaching this problem wrong.*

```
  const showTable = (props) => {
    return (
      <>
        {products && products.length !== 0 ? (
          products
            .filter((item) => item.category === props.table) // Kind of like this
            .map((product) => ExtendedProduct(product))
        ) : (
          <Loader />
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
```

```
  const TableRoutes = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {products &&
          productCategories.map((product) => (
            <Tab.Pane key={product.category} eventKey={product.category}>
              <ShowTable table={product.category} />
            </Tab.Pane>
          ))}
      </>
    );
  };
```

The `productCategories` is where I remove the duplicated categories so they won't be doubled when rendered.

The code above is a **functional component**.

I'm using https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/tabs/#tabs-custom-layout which explains `Tab.Pane`.

---

**Things I've looked into:**

- [Render products grouped by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180248/render-products-grouped-by-category) [class-based]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ~12 hours of fiddling around, apparently the solution is **quite** the same in the linked question.

[Render products grouped by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180248/render-products-grouped-by-category)

```
  const TableRoutes = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="default">
          <ExtendedTable
            data={
              products && products.map((product) => ExtendedProduct(product))
            }
          />
        </Tab.Pane>
        {/* Table filtered by product categories */}
        {products &&
          productCategories.map((categories) => (
            <Tab.Pane key={categories.category} eventKey={categories.category}>
              <ExtendedTable
                data={
                  products &&
                  products
                    .filter((pane) => pane.category === categories.category)
                    .map((product) => ExtendedProduct(product))
                }
              />
            </Tab.Pane>
          ))}
        {/* Table filtered by product types */}
        {products &&
          productTypes.map((types) => (
            <Tab.Pane key={types.type} eventKey={types.type}>
              <ExtendedTable
                data={
                  products &&
                  products
                    .filter((pane) => pane.type === types.type)
                    .map((product) => ExtendedProduct(product))
                }
              />
            </Tab.Pane>
          ))}
      </>
    );
  };
```

I guess this can be marked as duplicate...